# Integrating external JS into angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have modified a simple nfc on-detect, to send a simple byte array over in an separate cordova app using chariotstudios-nfc-plugin . The code is shown below.

index.js

```
 var app = {
 // Application Constructor
 initialize: function() {
 this.bindEvents();
 console.log("Starting NFC Reader app");
 },
 // Bind Event Listeners
 bindEvents: function() {
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
 },
 // deviceready Event Handler 
 onDeviceReady: function() {
 //app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
 nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
 app.onNfc, // tag successfully scanned
 function (status) { // listener successfully initialized
 app.display("Tap a tag to read its id number.");
 },
 function (error) { // listener fails to initialize
 app.display("NFC reader failed to initialize " +
 JSON.stringify(error));
 }
 );
 },

 onNfc: function(nfcEvent) {
 app.display("invoked function");
 var record = ndef.mimeMediaRecord('text/plain', '888');
 nfc.write(
        [record], 
        function () {
            app.display("Wrote data to tag.");
        }, 
        function (reason) {
          app.display("Problem");
        }
  );   



 },

 display: function(message) {
 var label = document.createTextNode(message),
 lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
 messageDiv.appendChild(lineBreak); // add a line break
 messageDiv.appendChild(label); // add the text
 },


 clear: function() {
 messageDiv.innerHTML = "";
 },


};
```

index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 app.initialize();
 </script>
```

The above works and tested. The problem I'm facing right now is that I would wish to just implement the nfc.write function into my ionic controller.

Snippet of the controller I'm trying to put (its mostly irrelevant to the question(retrieve items from db))

```
 .controller('NFC', function($scope, $timeout,$http, $filter,$ionicPopup,       
$stateParams, $cordovaSQLite, $cordovaDatePicker, dataFactory, StoreService){

    dataFactory.getDetails($stateParams.testId, testUserId).then(function(resp) {
    .....
```

Steps Taken To Resolve:

1. Calling external JS in the template html (console.log does not fire at all)
2. Calling JS inside the template html(console.log does not fire at all)

I would like to put this nfc.write into the controller. Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im still unable to put just the nfc.write into the controller only by itself.
The workaround is to use :

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function() {
   //javascript here
}
```

so as to load the JavaScript inside the controller which handles the view. Thanks all for the guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You can call any available functionality in your angular controller. Is your functionality global? Thne you can inject `$window` which is angular's wrapper for global window object and there access the functionality. The other part of story is to make angular process returned value cuz external calls are outside angulars digest cycle. for that check `$apply` or `$digest`.

Comment: Hi, i would only want to fire this nfc send function when it's at this page. I'm confused as in external JS which do initialization and onready all don't work on the controller or as an external JS script called by the template html.

Comment: Try `.controller('NFC', function($window, ...` then in controllers body: `$scope.callNfcWrite = function() { $window.nfc.write(); }`